# How to set up sorting data on postgres in alpine container?

Tags: postgresql, docker, alpine-linux

I'm using a **postgres:9-alpine** docker container and sorting data in table by varchar does not work correctly.

First, sorted by register then alphabetically, and I just need to alphabetically. 
I understand the problem in alpine locales.
How can I configure this?

example:

```
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('B a D c', ' ') ORDER BY 1;
```

shows: В,D,a,c

but I need: a,B,c,D

```
WITH foo AS (
SELECT regexp_split_to_table('B a D c', ' ') as bar
   )
SELECT bar FROM foo
ORDER BY bar collate "en_US.utf8";
```

ERROR: collation "en_US.utf8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

SELECT version():

*PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 6.2.1) 6.2.1 20160822, 64-bit*

Comment: Please add some example demonstrating the problem.

Comment: SELECT regexp_split_to_table('B a D c', ' ') ORDER BY 1; 
shows: В,D,a,c
but I need: a,B,c,D

Answer (score 1):

Give the result column an name and sort by e.g. lower():

```
SELECT c
from regexp_split_to_table('B a D c', ' ') as t(c)
ORDER BY lower(c);
```

---

In Postgres 10 you could use a case insensitive [ICU collation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/collation.html#COLLATION-CREATE) instead.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I need to fix this globally, and not in the query code.


Container does not have the correct locale

with foo as (
SELECT regexp_split_to_table ('B a D c', '') as bar
    )
SELECT bar FROM foo
ORDER BY bar collate "en_US.utf8";


ERROR: collation "en_US.utf8" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist

Comment: @happy_yar: so what is your **exact** Postgres version? [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47437821/edit) your question and add the result of `select version()`. In Postgres 9.x you will need to find a operating system collation that does case-insensitive sorting. So you also need to tell us which operating system (and version) you are using (again: edit your question)

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6.6 on x86_64-pc-linux-musl, compiled by gcc (Alpine 6.2.1) 6.2.1 20160822, 64-bit